# Enums and subtraction operator

Tags: c#, enums

Does anyone know (and perhaps: since when) the `-=` operator is supported on `enum` values?

I was happily coding away today when I, for some reason, wrote this to exclude a value from a flags `enum`:

```
flags -= FlagsEnum.Value1;
```

After rereading and evaluating my code, I was surprised that it compiled actually worked.

Writing the statement as

```
flags = flags - FlagsEnum.Value1
```

however does ***not*** compile.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation and on internet so far. Also, other operators (apart from the bit operators, of course) are not supported: `+=` (including a flag) , `*=` (intersection in Pascal) don't work.

Is this some syntactic sugar built into the C# compiler? If so, any reason why they chose not to include other operators?

A simple code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    [Flags]
    enum FlagsEnum
    {
        None = 0,
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2,
        Value3 = 4
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FlagsEnum flags = FlagsEnum.Value1 | FlagsEnum.Value2 | FlagsEnum.Value3;
            Console.WriteLine(flags);
            flags -= FlagsEnum.Value1;
            Console.WriteLine(flags);
            flags -= FlagsEnum.Value3;
            Console.WriteLine(flags);
            flags -= FlagsEnum.Value2;
            Console.WriteLine(flags);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it actually works? You could be deceived by the fact that a subtraction will appear to exclude the bit. Have you tried it on a flags variable where the bit corresponding to Value1 is already 0?

Comment: Using it like that is pretty unsafe. It will only work as enum when `FlagsEnum.Value1` is already in the `flags`.

Comment: @Jaroslav: I never do it like that, but it just happened to roll out of my fingers. I blame it on Delphi (with its nice set operators), but I was quite (although now less) surprised that it compiled. And, as Marc pointed out, the result might not be wat you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enumeration subtraction. Every enumeration type implicitly provides the following predefined operator, where E is the enum type, and U is the underlying type of E:
U operator –(E x, E y);
This operator is evaluated exactly as (U)((U)x – (U)y). In other words, the operator computes the difference between the ordinal values of x and y, and the type of the result is the underlying type of the enumeration.

[source](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_14.7.5_Subtraction_operator)

I hope you know that you can define the implicit values for enum members, so if you give them values x=5, y=10, z=15 and you will try to do z-y, you will get x.

Comment: Aaah...the specs. :) The only place I didn't look (and almost never look, to be honest). Thanks. Any idea why the += operator was not defined in a similar way for enums?

Comment: both works but when you write E -= E it's already casted to E, when you try to do it E = E - E way you should use implicit cast E = (MyEnum)(E - E)

Answer (score 36):

Iirc, `-` is still integer subtraction.

To do exclusion you want:

```
value = value & ~SomeEnum.Flag;
```

And inclusion:

```
value = value | SomeEnum.Flag;
```

Likewise, to test for a partial match (any bit from Flag):

```
if((value & SomeEnum.Flag) != 0) {...}
```

Or a full match (all the bits in Flag):

```
if((value & SomeEnum.Flag) == SomeEnum.Flag) {...}
```

Comment: Who downvoted this?  `& (~flag)` is the correct technique for removing flags, `| (flag)` for adding them, and `&` for intersection.

Comment: Yes, that's the "normal" way. Hence my question.

Comment: @Marc: I *know* how enums work. That's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @Willem - ou missed my point; you claim "it works"; the spec says this is integer subtaction. Which isn't what you want to remove a bit (question). so IMO this **doesn't** work in the way you think (question).

Comment: @Marc: Hmmm...you're right. One up :). For what it's worth: I was  definitely not planning on using it. Don't know what triggered me to write the statement like that, but most likely it was a Delphi-ism from yesterday. I *was* mightely surprised though.

Comment: @Marc: a guru like you could help me... why does `Enum1 -= Enum2` compile and `Enum1 = Enum1 - Enum2` doesn't ? Looking at reflected code, it seems that in the first case, compiler has turn `Enum2` into its underlying value...but why ?

Comment: @Willem - is the underlying type perhaps short/byte? If so, their - always returns int, so need an extra cast to get back to the underlying type; -= has special handling to not need the cast